# Software updater doesn't work anymore correctly

Tags: release-freya

Today I tried about 12 Times to install some updates ... without any result:

First problem: The software updater needs about 20 to 30 Minutes to check for the updates, which seems not normal to me (normally not more than 2 minutes).

Second problem: After authenticate for updates with password there comes the following info: "software updater: Requires installation of untrusted packages. This requires packages from unauthenticated sources." When I click »okay« the software updater disappears.

What can I do to install the updates?﻿

Comment: It sounds like you've added some new software sources (maybe a PPA?). That's the "untrusted packages" bit. Can you try disabling/removing any non-default sources and see if that solves it?

Comment: It can't be the problem, because the only extra software on the system is an firefox-browser, nothing else. I made dozens of updates, in the last months and they all worked fine. I didn't install anything in this time.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to open the terminal and type these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Wait after process update's done.

Then run this command

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Have you tried that command on your terminal? Then of the end command update and upgrade list what's the result? Any error notes on your terminal?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the recommendation ... it worked without any error notes on the terminal. :-)

Comment: ok then, is your problem solved?

Comment: Yes ... the problem is solved.

Comment: congratulations :)

Comment: @oxidaviah , would please accept this answer as it is the one that works for you.

Comment: @ferry, why wiki? you need such reputation ;). Please, check https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts